# Delete messages from specific durable Tibco EMS subscription

Tags: java, tibco, ems

I have Tibco EMS server, some topics and number of durable subscriptions to this topics(more than one to every topic).
My task is to delete(by receiving them with appropriate acknowledge mode) messages for specific durable subscriber.
My question: is it possible to manage subscriber's pending messages by "substitute" it with my own subscriber(with the same name, id)? And it's important not to affect topic's pending messages, in other words, delete some messages from one topic subscription, but remain those messages in other topic(the same topic) subscription.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Each subscriber receives their own copy of the message. If you create a subscriber, you cannot get message intended for another subscriber.  You might find the answer in this link helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284143/how-to-remove-messages-from-a-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer, just forgot to post it before.

As mentioned above, under question itself, there is no way to delete messages from topic. But I had little different task: to delete messages under specific *durable* subscription. And this is real(with some conditions).

Lets say, you have to delete messages from *durable* subscription "MySubscr". To do so you should create connection and create Durable Subscriber with same name "MySubscr". But it's not enough. If you just do so, then another durable subscriber will be created with the same name, but under connection with different *ClientID* . And it will operate as standalone durable connection without any impact to required "MySubscr" durable(actually, they will look like MySubscr:123 and MySubscr:567 durable subscription, where 123 and 567 are the ClientIDs, at least for TibcoEMS). To fix it, you should set ClientID explicitly to your connection by *connection.setClientID()* method, but you can do it only if initial connection is not connected(that's why I noted about *durable* subscriber, it can accumulate messages without subscriber connected).

So you should wait until subscriber will disconnect by itself(*isConnected()* method for TibcoEMS, I didn't see similar method in JMS API, but suppose most of implementations have something like this) or to destroy connection(with certain ClientID) manually(*TibjmsAdmin.destroyConnection()* method from TibcoEMS). And after this set the ClientID to your connection and get access to the messages of this subscriber. You can read messages by consuming them with Acknowledge mode Client(then they will remain in the topic), or with the mode Auto(then they will be deleted).

**Important note:** you can't consume some certain message, all the messages are consumed like in queue, so you can do it only one-by-one. If you found some unwanted message and wish to delete it(by consuming with autoacknowledge mode or by calling *acknowledge()* method on the message) then you'll lost all prior messages with it. AFAIK, there is no way to delete message without deleting prior ones.

**Another important note:** while you doing your messages magic it is important for the initial client not to connect again till your connection isn't closed, because it will get DublicateClientIDException(if it is using certain ClientID) or it will create another Durable Subscription which will have no access to the prior messages from the subscription.